# How to display an image whose path is saved in the database in a data list control?

Tags: c#

how to display an image whose path is stored in the database onto the aspx page, i am using the data list control, and also onclick of the image, the user details has to load. the image path and user id are in the same table.please send the code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/NewsImages/" + FileName);

mallDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("NewsImagePath", filePath);
```